# Angularjs execute after function ( promise ? )

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to execute the $window only after the for loop is completed. How do I do that? Do I have to add promise or something? If so, how do I do so? I tried looking at questions that uses promise but I don't really understand. Would really appreciate your help and thanks!

```
 var getAllTheme = displayAll.callAll()
     .then(function(response) {
         $scope.allTheme = response;
         for (var i =0; i < $scope.allTheme.length; i++) {
           if ( i > 0) {
                $scope.themename.push($scope.allTheme[i].THEMENAME);
           }
         }
     })


       $scope.searchFunction = function() {
          for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.allTheme.length; i++) {
              if ($scope.selected == $scope.allTheme[i].THEMENAME)
              {
                  $scope.selectedTheme = $scope.allTheme[i].QUERYNAME;
                  apiURL = 'url';
                  $scope.selected = $scope.allTheme[i].THEMENAME;
                      $http.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.apiResult = response.data.SrchResults;
                        $scope.apiResult.splice(0,1);
                        for (var i= 0; i < $scope.apiResult.length; i++) {
                             $scope.dataLatLng.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
                        }

                      })
                      $window.location.href = "#!/searchedResult";
              }


          }

       }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="searchFeature" ng-model="selected"
       ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && searchFunction()"
       uib-typeahead="value for value in themename | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7" 
       placeholder="Start your search here.">
```

Comment: Why would you even need to modify the scope if you are going to immediately redirect? Seems like you would want a service for the data

Comment: As for the making the requests before redirect make array of them and use `$q.all()` to call for redirect

Comment: How does creating a service work ? @charlietfl

Comment: Allows storing the data for re-use anywhere in the app whereas a controller instance is destroyed when you leave that route

Comment: Also doesn't make sense overwriting the same scope variables every iteration of the loop

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and what do you mean by overwriting the same scope variable? Are you referring to the $scope.selected? I updated my code @charlietfl

Comment: Things like `$scope.apiResult=` and `$scope.selectedTheme =`. Will only get value of last iteration

Comment: So, I have to create a service and store the information when my searchFunction is called? But how do I like pass it to my "searchedResult" page? They are both using the same controller. Both the searchPage and SearchedResult page.

Comment: Well they might be using same controller code but each one will use a new instance of that controller. What router are you using?

Comment: $routeProvider?

Comment: OK so that is `ngRoute` router. In order to access the same data in other route will need an angular service that you inject in controller

Comment: Hmm, sorry I am confused. ( Still new to coding ). Service is someting like myApp.service('service' function($http){} right? What do I store in there? My for loop data?

Comment: Yes that's how you create one. There are lots of tutorials around how to use it

Comment: PS: The scope I am trying to retrieve is $scope.selected and $scope.apiResult

Comment: Ok, so what's going on is, I create a service to store my for loop data, and I call it again when I navigate to my searchedResult page?

Comment: Basically yes....tutorials will help you understand better

Comment: Alright, thanks alot for clarifying things up!!

Comment: @ITnyp Your code looks correct .But $scope.themename and $scope.AllThem should be blobal declaretaion

Comment: Nothing is showing up when I search. Unless I put my search function in the same page as my result page (which is not what I want). Trying to figure on how to create a service which isn't going too well D: @LDS

Comment: your result should be same page .But may be in modal popup or hide unhide